# How do I convert this Activity into a Fragment?

Tags: android, gridview, android-activity, fragment

I have found this code which does exactly what I need for my app, however it runs as a Activity.

What do I need to change to convert it to a Fragment? Since there only 3 errors when extending it to a Fragment instead of an Activity I have a feeling it isn't too hard to convert?

I would really need to use this piece of code but it must be a Fragment instead, since my app uses a navigation drawer which creates new Fragments as views.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GridView photoGrid;
private int mPhotoSize, mPhotoSpacing;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

// Some items to add to the GRID
private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { 
        "Test Item" };

private static final int[] ICONS = new int[] {R.drawable.test };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get the photo size and spacing
    mPhotoSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_size);
    mPhotoSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_spacing);

    // initialize image adapter
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();

    photoGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.albumGrid);

    // set image adapter to the GridView
    photoGrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    // get the view tree observer of the grid and set the height and numcols dynamically
    photoGrid.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (imageAdapter.getNumColumns() == 0) {
                final int numColumns = (int) Math.floor(photoGrid.getWidth() / (mPhotoSize + mPhotoSpacing));
                if (numColumns > 0) {
                    final int columnWidth = (photoGrid.getWidth() / numColumns) - mPhotoSpacing;
                    imageAdapter.setNumColumns(numColumns);
                    imageAdapter.setItemHeight(columnWidth);

                }
            }
        }
    });
}

// ///////// ImageAdapter class /////////////////
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mItemHeight = 0;
    private int mNumColumns = 0;
    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mImageViewLayoutParams;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return CONTENT.length;
    }

    // set numcols
    public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
        mNumColumns = numColumns;
    }

    public int getNumColumns() {
        return mNumColumns;
    }

    // set photo item height
    public void setItemHeight(int height) {
        if (height == mItemHeight) {
            return;
        }
        mItemHeight = height;
        mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mItemHeight);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null)
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_item, null);

        ImageView cover = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cover);
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

        cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);

        // Check the height matches our calculated column width
        if (cover.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {
            cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
        }

        cover.setImageResource(ICONS[position % ICONS.length]);
        title.setText(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);

        return view;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for general coding help, not help with a specific problem. It will not help future visitors.

Comment: My specific problem is that I need to convert a Activity into a Fragment, and this is the scenario. Isn't this suitable for a question? :( I would be so happy if I could get it solved and I don't know where else to search. Thanks

Comment: The problem here is that you want *this specific* activity converted into a fragment. That'll help only you. Why not start converting it, and then ask when you run into problems that others can benefit from? As is, you're asking someone to do very basic work for you.

Comment: I see what you mean. Actually I've tried converting it multiple times but I end up with the app crashing. I thought that it would be easier to just give the source code instead of describing every single move I made and what errors I've gotten. I simply did it like this to save time, space and confusion for all of us. Thanks.

Comment: Sure it's easier -- for you. But then you probably won't learn it, and it'll be frustrating for you to have to ask over and over again. And it'll clutter up the site with useless noise.

Comment: Then please, would you kindly tell me, in detail, how I should ask this question, or similar ones, instead for someone to help me. Apparently I'm doing something wrong and would like to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend Fragment instead of Activity, then use the `onCreateView` method to return the view, instead of the `onCreate` method. You would need to include the following code to combine the fragment with its xml.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
```

Then continue with your code. Whenever you have a widget, it should be implemented like in this example:

```
TextView info = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.Address);
```

Finally, if you have any further code which shows errors, precede the underlined code with `getActivity().`

All of the above needs to be only done to the MainActivity class and not to the adapter.